# put selected value from db in mat option angular 12

Tags: angular, angular12, mat-select

i want to put selected value from add action that already save in database to show in edit action in `mat-select` or `mat-option`. this `mat-select` is also used for add action. in add action, the value is empty while in edit action the value from db should be shown. the selected value is a foreign key in table A that is a primary key in the table B

my .html file is below

```
                <mat-form-field  appearance="outline" > 
                    <mat-select placeholder="Pilih Ruang " [(value)]="selected1" name="NAMA_RUANG" [(ngModel)]="dataKamar.ID_RUANG">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let row of dataRuang" [value]="row.KODE_RUANG">{{row.NAMA_RUANG}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

my .ts file is below
to call dataRuang

```
  getRuang(){
    this.api_ruang.baca().subscribe((result: any)=> {
      this.dataRuang = result;
    })
  }
```

to call dataKamar

```
  getAll(){
    this.api_kamar.getList().subscribe((result: any) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result)
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
    })  

  }
```

to save

```
  addItem(){
    this.dataKamar.ID_RUANG = this.selected1;
    this.api_kamar.addItem(this.dataKamar).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.getAll()
      this.cancelEdit()     
    })
  }
```

to edit

```
  editItem(element: any){
    this.dataKamar = _.cloneDeep(element)
    this.isEdit = true
  }


  updateItem(){
    this.api_kamar.updateItem(this.dataKamar.ID_KAMAR, this.dataKamar).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.getAll()
      this.cancelEdit()      
    })
  }
```

how i can put the selected value from database into the `mat-option`?

thank you

Comment: `selected1` should be `row.KODE_RUANG`

Comment: it's still not working because the row is belong to mat-option. or maybe should i move it to where?